# strip white space after :

Tags: python, regex, string, escaping

**this is my code** it prints with lots of space after OS Name: how to strip off the white space? was trying to use split, I guess did not use it in right way

OS Name:Microsoft Windows 7 Professional

See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2344941

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, os

lineContains = re.compile('.*OS Name.*')
lineHas = re.compile('.*OS Version.*')

filename = open("system-info.txt", 'r')
for line in filename:
    if lineContains.match(line):
        ''.join(line.split())
        print line
        if "Windows 7" in line:
            print 'See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2344941'
        else:
            print 'See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2550978'    
filename.close()
```

Comment: `''.join(line.split())` doesn't change the original string. You know that, right?

Comment: ^ strings arent mutable, that line returns a new string

Comment: word =''.join(line.split()), tried this it gets rid of all whitespace

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX to strip of white space. `myString.replaceAll("\\s+","")` will eliminate multiple white spaces. However, there are white spaces that are not necessarily "spaces". For these you can use `myString.replaceAll("\\W+", "")`.

Comment: i tried replaceAll,**if lineContains.match(line):
  word = line.strip("\\W+", "")
  print word**                                           gave me this error: **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hotfix.py", line 10, in <module>
    word = line.strip("\\W+", "")
TypeError: strip() takes at most 1 argument (2 given) **

Comment: if lineContains.match(line):
  Name = re.sub('+',r': ',line)
  print Name
  if "Windows 7" in Name:
   print 'See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2344941'
  else:
   print 'See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2550978' **does not work this way**

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use `line = re.sub(r':[\t ]+',r': ',line)`. That will take any colon and all the whitespace after it and replace it with a single colon and a space so that you have a guaranteed amount of whitespace after every colon.

Comment: i tried this with my code and it does not seem to work, really bad at regex so any help or instruction would be helpful thank you **'#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, os, string
lineContains = re.compile('.*OS Name.*')
lineHas = re.compile('.*OS Version.*')
filename = open("system-info.txt", 'r')
for line in filename:
 if lineContains.match(line):
  Name = re.sub(r':[\t]+',r': ',line)
  print Name
  if "Windows 7" in line:
   print 'See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2344941'
  else:
   print 'See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2550978' 
filename.close()'** @RevanProdigalKnight

Comment: @user3731311 The problem is that you made the results of the regex replace go into a new variable, `Name`, so while that variable had the correct result, the contents of `line` went unchanged because in Python all string manipulation returns a new string instead of modifying the original. I remember when I originally picked up Python that confused me as well.  If you change the line `if "Windows 7" in line:` to `if "Windows 7" in Name:` or change `Name = re.sub(...)` to `line = re.sub(...)` it should work.

Comment: still the same does not take out spaces after OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7..

Comment: @user3731311 So that I can keep track, which change did you make?

Comment: @user3731311 I also just now noticed that when you put in my regex line, you got rid of the space after `\t` in `r':[\t ]'`. That was actually supposed to be there and was not a typo; if you get rid of that it will ignore spaces.

Comment: (+',r': ',line), this way?

Comment: @user3731311 I'm not entirely sure I know what you're trying to ask. Just copy everything in re.sub() from my answer and it should work.  If not, I'll put up a pastebin link with code that should work and comments to explain what I'm doing.

Comment: i tried it but does not work

Comment: @user3731311 if [this](http://pastebin.com/NkfYnDWB) doesn't work exactly as it is, then I don't know what you're looking for.